# Unable to perform Update sql from php

Tags: php, mysql

The following is my code

```
try {
                 $pdo = Database::connect();
                 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
               //$sql = "UPDATE usermaster SET Password=?, UserName=?, OwnerOrEmp=?, DBName=?, DeleteFlag=?, UpdateDate=? WHERE UserId = ?";
                $sql = "UPDATE usermaster SET Password=:password, UserName=:userName, OwnerOrEmp=:ownerOrEmp, DBName=:dBName, DeleteFlag=:deleteFlag, UpdateDate=:updateDate WHERE UserId = :id";
                $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $q->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 8);
                $q->bindParam(':userName', $name);
                $q->bindParam(':password', $pass);
                $q->bindParam(':ownerOrEmp', $ownEmp);
                $q->bindParam(':dBName', $dbName);
                $q->bindParam(':deleteFlag', $delEmp);
                $q->bindParam(':updateDate', $curr_date);
                $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($pass,$name,$ownEmp,$dbName,$delEmp,$curr_date, $id));
            Database::connect();

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            //die($e->getMessage());
            $db_error = "".$e->getMessage();
        }
        header("Location: ShainIndex.php");
    }
```

Request your kind insight, this piece of code alone does not get executed and update is not executed...Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the second prepare

Comment: remove  this one $q = $pdo->prepare($sql); in last presence

Comment: Thank you for pointing at my silliest mistakes. :) Am Updating my code. shall post again if I find the appropriate results.

Answer (score 0):

your preparing same query twice

```
         $q->bindParam(':updateDate', $curr_date);
           // $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);  //comment this line
        $q->execute(array($pass,$name,$ownEmp,$dbName,$delEmp,$curr_date, $id));
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally began to debug each and every single variables value being inserted, as shown in the above bindParam(). It turned out that by default or due to some string handling there happened to a space(" ") being inserted into many many of the values of those variables. 
So, what this space was causing was, that it did not allow the value to be matched on the database to the inputed data coming from the view.
Due to which especially the "id"  field receive values with spaces...like " 00100001" although it is not easily visible it never matched with "00100001" value in the db's table.
Thus, this took me the whole day and almost cost me my job. In some place a small "-" broke down an entire satellite launching rocket.
So, I am in a way blogging my "Word of Caution" to all those whose life ticks on one tiny bit of characters.
Thanks to all those who provided their valuable inputs and time.